# Modulo Arithmetic of Complex Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Suppose $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$a+b+c\in \mathbb{Z},$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=-3,$$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=-46,$$
$$a^4+b^4+c^4=-123$$

then find $(a^{10}+b^{10}+c^{10})\pmod{1000}$.

I only observed that the sum of imaginary part of $a,b,c$ is $0$, and all of $-3,-46,-123$ are divisible by $3$. But I don't know if it's going to help. Also, I think there is something to do with Gaussian integers?

Comment: $46$ is divisible by $3$? News to me. :)

Comment: @Deepak Sure it is ... in base $9$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $a,b,c$ be the roots of the cubic $f(x)=x^3-px^2+qx-r=0$ and let $s_k=a^k+b^k+c^k$

Then evaluate $x^kf(x)$ at $a,b,c$ and add to obtain the recurrence $s_{k+3}-ps_{k+2}+qs_{k+1}-rs_k=0$

Note that $s_0=3$. Now you need to work out how to use the data you have and keep the calculations under control.